# MongoDB Visual Studio Code extension: how to find by ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code

I'm using the following extension:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/mongodb

To perform queries and light data transformation against a Mongo database. I'm having trouble working out how to issue a find request which matches an ObjectId.

I tried:

```
db.Epochs.find({
    'ModelId': '624616797870316ac1432d52'
}).sort({'End': -1})
```

This results in an empty result set (this ID definitely exists because I copied that value from Compass.

I tried:

```
db.Epochs.find({
    'ModelId': ObjectId'624616797870316ac1432d52')
}).sort({'End': -1})
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Unexpected token, expected "," (15:23) 13 | 14 | db.Epochs.find({ > 15 | 'ModelId': ObjectId('624616797870316ac1432d52') | ^ 16 | }).sort({'End': -1}) 17 | 18 | //'EndLogs._impl': { '$exists': true}
```

I tried adding the NodeJS driver setup calls like:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
    assert = require('assert');
```

Which errors with:

```
Cannot find module 'mongodb' Require stack: - c:\Users\Ian\.vscode\extensions\mongodb.mongodb-vscode-0.9.2\dist\languageServerWorker.js
```

Finally I tried:

```
db.Epochs.find({
    'ModelId': { '$oid': '624616797870316ac1432d52' }
}).sort({'End': -1})
```

Which errors with:

```
unknown operator: $oid
```

Comment: Is this a typo, there is a opening bracket missing in `ObjectId'624616797870316ac1432d52')`?

Comment: @Robert Yes that was a typo, I tried it again just now with the typo fixed and it still errored. Thanks!

Comment: "... because I copied that value from Compass"  And you are certain that you are connecting to the same server/database/collection?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get a single document using the following query

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName')
  .find({"_id":  ObjectId("6459019b5152f2e5c5adb03f")})
```